# How can I launch several different kernels for multiple evaluation of many scripts mean Linux terminal?

Tags: kernel

I have several scripts to launch, with the command: math.9 < script_name.m, on a server Linux based mean Linux terminal. The Mathematica version on the server is Mathematica 9. I know that I cannot launch more than 7 processes per Kernel. Is there a way to start another Kernel mean terminal command or should I use Parallelize inside the script? (Even if I do this way, I cannot start the Mathematica because it say me that I've reached the maximum number of processes).

Thanks for the help

Comment: With 11.3 you can use `WolframScript`?

Comment: The Mathematica version on the server il the 9th. I run my script in the server with the command: math.9 <file_name.m. It is the only command that I found to run that script in this server...
In any case, I would like, if it is possible, to start another Kernel session "manually" using terminal command, or is it mandatory to act before inside the script to change kernel?